# How to run a maven test in parallel with maven install?

Tags: java, maven, testng

I have a `testng` test like this

```
@Test
public void test(){

    for(String s:list){

     // doing the test
     }

}
```

The test time increases as the contents in `list` increases. If a single iteration takes X milliseconds, then for a 100 iteration its gonna take 100X milliseconds.

I want to reduce the maven build time so I thought of running the test in parallel.

Is there any way for my `testng` test to run in parallel with the remaining maven build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use paralleled Dataprovider

```
@DataProvider(parallel = true)
public Object[][] listToArrays() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList();
    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    list.add("3");
    list.add("4");
    Object[][] array = new Object[list.size()][1];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        array[i][0] = list.get(i);
    }
    return array;
}

@Test(dataProvider = "listToArrays")
public void test(String s) {
    System.out.println(s + " " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    //do your test with s
}
```

p.s. I don't know the context, but feel that you doing something wrong

Comment: Many thanks for this. This is exactly what I needed.